# Web camera, heart monitor or tools for online medical appointments?

Tags: camera, webcam

With the current Covid-19 outbreak, many people and families are doing remote/telehealth medical appointments. I'm thinking, as a precaution, to get the tools needed in case someone in my family gets sick or must get quarantined.

I'm wondering what webcam/tools would be good here? Some good features:

- Very high res and works well in medium-light conditions.
- Wireless or long wire might be good, so doctor can look into your ear.
- Any devices that allow looking into crevices like ear.
- Something to measure vital signs, like blood pressure, blood oxygen and pulse rate
- USB Stethoscope- because, (like a programmer debugging) I think hearing the beat itself, if it skips, etc, gives doctors a better clue. Also for stomach issues, often a doctor uses it, or for lung checks while you breath.
- Would be interesting to go beyond conventional, like an infrared camera? Would that even be useful?
- What else?

**What I found so far:**
Remember, I am not a doctor and have near-zero medical training. Please consult a doctor or health person.

For ears/eye/spot exams:

- [https://www.amazon.com/Inspection-1-3Megapixels-Waterproof-Adjustable-Compatible/dp/B07JHJWKCY/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JHJWKCY)

Or in Canada:
  - https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07H3RQR3M/

Blood Pressure:
  - [https://www.amazon.com/iHealth-Bluetooth-Monitor-MFi-Certified-FSA-Eligible/dp/B00ANJAKF8/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00ANJAKF8)

Blood oxygen levels:
  - https://smile.amazon.com/Zacurate-Fingertip-Oximeter-Saturation-batteries/dp/B07B9X3DBX/
(But not USB. History would be important. USB ones are too expensive, over $99. Does anyone know of a cheaper option?)

USB Stethoscope:
  - http://www.usbsteth.com/pcp-usb-stethoscopes/
But the order page says "not found". Anyone know of a place to buy one?

I wish there was a simple "remote health" all in one hardware package. Anyone know if better options than these?

Comment: Quick update- I got the ear endoscope here: https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07H3RQR3M/ and it was very good. I could use it for my ear, inspect skin, and probably much more.

Answer (score 1):

What I found was a digital USB stethoscope with optional Pulse Ox  https://www.ebay.com/itm/CON-TEC-CMS-VE-Visual-Digital-Stethoscope-ECG-SPO2-PR-Electronic-Diagnostic-ECG-/263690719589 or digital USB stethoscope with PC interface and SD card storage plus optional Pulse OX https://www.ebay.com/itm/CONTEC-Visual-Digital-Stethoscope-ECG-SPO2-PR-Electronic-Diagnostic-Bluetooth-CE/253958038129 . This adds BlueTooth (no idea which profile): https://www.ebay.com/itm/Bluetooth-Visual-Digital-Stethoscope-ECG-SPO2-PR-Electronic-Diagnostic-CMS-VESD/122874341655?

Comment: Caution to buyers- not clear if these are FDA approved. 1 of them claims to be. Others aren't clear, for example it says the Fingertip Pulse Monitor is, but its ambiguous about the whole device. Do your own research.